# Wacom Graphics Tablet CTH-480 / CTL-480 Not Detected In Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wacom

My Wacom tablet (CTH-480) is not detected by the Wacom Tablet option under settings. The Tablet shows up when I run `lsusb` but does not show up under settings. Again Thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (same device, same Ubuntu release) ... hopefully someone comes up with an answer soon!

Comment: Hi Bradley can you set the answer below as correct? I just followed the instructions and is working smooth. I find fair that you give it as correct and other people can also enjoy

Comment: Will it be supported in 14.04 out of the box?

Comment: I tried a beta image of 14.04 now (2013-01-07). The tablet is not detected out of the box. I hope the driver will be pushed upstream before release... if someone knows where to ask for inclusion, please tell me and I will look into it.

Comment: I checked a beta of 14.04 on a virtualbox VM today, and using the "passthru" USB driver, the tablet has been detected automatically without the need of any additional driver. Unless the virtualbox layer is doing some strange thing, is a good news for 14.04!

Comment: Has anyone checked it with 14.04 Trusty Thar? I have a nasty behavior https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1310800

Answer (score 12):

### Update for 14.04

**Short (really) version**. The tablet works out of the box, [but sometime you need to manually load the driver](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1310800) with `sudo modprobe wacom` before attaching (or switching on if wireless) the tablet.

Nevertheless, the following instruction can be helpful if some new tablet comes out which has support in the upstream driver but not in the stock kernel.

### Update for 13.10, 14 Dec 2013, input-wacom >= 0.20.0

**Short version:** you do not need to patch input-wacom anymore starting from version 0.20.0, and you do not *strictly* need to update the X.org input driver in 13.10.

**Long version:**

For 13.10, if you accept to forego the new things added to `x86-input-wacom` (at this time: 14 Dec 2013,  looking at changelogs, it's some stuff about better touch behavior) you can simplify it a lot.

Basic information is still from the [main answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/371975/16395), and from [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=110408), with a slight difference.

1) Download the last version of input-wacom kernel driver. It should be at least 0.20.0, otherwise the tablet will not be detected, from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/. In date 2013-12-14, the newest is `input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2`.

2) be sure to have the build dependencies installed. Upgrade your system if you have not, so you have the last kernel. If it says that a reboot is needed, reboot before continuing (this is to avoid to build against a wrong kernel).

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libX11-dev libxi-dev x11proto-input-dev xserver-xorg-dev libxrandr-dev libncurses5-dev autoconf libtool
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Notice that if `uname -r` tell you that you have a special kernel (ending not in -generic, but -rt, or -lowlatency, or whatever, you should modify the second apt-get accordingly)

2) uncompress the driver in a directory of your choice. Move the downloaded file in that direcory, `cd` to it, and

```
tar xjvf input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2
```

3) a directory `input-wacom-0.20.0` is created. `cd` to it and compile the drivers:

```
cd  input-wacom-0.20.0
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

**Update** In versions prior to 0.27 or whereabout, that started the compilation too. If using a newer one, you need to issue

```
 make   # only for versions >= 0.27.0
```

if there are no errors, at the end you have a message starting with:

```
  BUILD ENVIRONMENT:
       linux kernel - yes 3.7
      kernel source - yes /lib/modules/3.11.0-14-generic/build

Your wacom.ko is available under 
    /home/romano/software/wacom/input-wacom-0.20.0/3.7
[...more stuff...]
```

You have kernel 3.11.something, not 3.7 --- do not worry. It's ok.

4) Install the driver. For versions < 0.27.0, you have to use:

```
sudo cp ./3.7/wacom.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko
sudo depmod -a
```

otherwise, for a more recent version, just do

```
sudo make install
```

If you had not the tablet connected since the last reboot (i.e. you had no kernel module wacom.ko loaded), a reboot is not needed. You can just plug your tablet and go. Otherwise, reboot.

**NOTICE:** Every time the kernel is updated, you need to repeat step 3 and 4 (*)(you better add a

```
make clean
```

in the driver directory before the `./configure` step to rebuild all anew).

(*) you have to do the installation AFTER rebooting in the new kernel, because otherwise the `uname -r` tricks will install the module in the wrong place...

**AND ANOTHER NOTICE:** if you tablet works, but it does not show up in the control panel, [look at this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/411365/16395) and

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks! Just as a side question: can I move the directory input-wacom-0.20.0 afterwards or will this mess everything up? I did the whole procedure in the downloads directory but would like to move it to another place...

Comment: You can move it wherever you want. When you have a kernel upgrade, `cd` to the directory, do `make clean`, and restart from point 3)

Comment: Off-topic question/side remark: I would like to remove the Wacom related entries in System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Other software because I think they cause these silly "update information outdated" messages I get all the time. Have these entries been added by the process described in your post? Can I delete them without harming the functionality of my tablet again?

Comment: I really don't know what could be the problem. The procedure listed here does not modify any repository info --- uses just the stock packages for comiling things. The message you have is often caused by a PPA or something like that that went offline. Last time it happened to me was because of Medibuntu (which is no more).

Comment: OK, but can I remove the wacom entries from the update list? Or will that cause problems?

Comment: I don't really know --- which are this "entries from the update list"? If you mean remove packages as for example xorg-xinput-wacom or similar no, you can't; if you mean removing some PPA experimental repository repository yes, you can. Maybe opening another question with the output of "sudo apt-get update" showing the erros can help.

Comment: Strange, since the last update (yesterday) the tablet doesn't work any more. I have even removed input-wacom-0.20.0 and extracted the compressed file again (so that all files should be fresh). Then I ran through steps 3) and 4) again. But it still doesn't work ... Any idea what's wrong!?

Comment: I had to do an additional reboot but now (it seems) to work --- I will test more this afternoon. The procedure is: update kernel, reboot, **then** rebuild and install the driver, then reboot. The real solution will be to learn to use `dkms`, but well... no time for it. Hint for someone willing to do it and editing the answer... ;-)

Comment: Well, I did this rebooting but still it doesn't work. But I will try it again ...

Comment: OK, it does work now!?!

Answer (score 1):

The tablet is too fresh :-) the input-wacom developers are working on support in the upcoming release of input-wacom (kernel driver) and x86-input-wacom (xserver input driver) as soon as the patches are accepted into the kernel upstream, they will release the new version.

If you don't want to wait that long to get your new tablet going -- the solution is to compile the kernel-module and xserver-driver yourself - I have 12.04 running with 3.8.0-32-lowlatency kernel from the kxstudio ppa, so I don't know if this works with the stock 3.2 kernel but since you are on 13.10, that shouldn't be a problem. You have to follow the instructions on the linux-wacom website on how to compile the kernel module and the xserver driver almost to the letter but you have to apply three patches in the process. Be sure to install all the build-dependencies needed and mentioned on the linux-wacom website.

The gist of it is

```
 mkdir ~/wacom
 cd ~/wacom
 git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom
 git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/linuxwacom/input-wacom
```

Now you need two patches for the kernel module, posted by a wacom developer in this thead http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/mailman/message/31592023/ as attachments to this post http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/mailman/message/31599376/

- 0001-Input-wacom-Not-all-multi-interface-devices-support-.patch
- 0002-Input-wacom-add-support-for-three-new-Intuos-devices.patch

Apply them

```
cd input-wacom
patch -p1 < ~/Downloads/0001-Input-wacom-Not-all-multi-interface-devices-support-.patch
patch -p1 < ~/Downloads/0002-Input-wacom-add-support-for-three-new-Intuos-devices.patch
```

compile the module

```
./autogen.sh
./make
```

then make a backup of the old module and install the freshly build

```
sudo cp /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko.BAK
sudo cp 3.7/wacom.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko
sudo depmod -a
```

To get a working xserver driver you have to apply a patch to get the git-sources to work with the ubuntu 12.04 xserver, the build_against_frankenserver.patch - the patch is available e.g. attachment in this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515562&page=104 , I don't know if this is still necessecary with 13.04 or 13.10! (and ignore patch failures in the test/ directory)

```
cd ../xf86-input-wacom
patch -p1 ~/Downloads/build_against_frankenserver.patch
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib
make
```

Install it

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/wacom_drv.so /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/wacom_drv.so.BAK
sudo cp src/.libs/wacom_drv.so /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/wacom_drv.so
```

Reboot or restart and it should work.

Again be sure to read all the information given to you over at linux-wacom.sf.net, this is only a rough summary, and I wont have the time to help in depth anytime soon.

Still, I hope this helps -- the Intuos PTS is a really cool device, and it works like a charm this way.

Comment: Thank you for your response... was hoping for an easy fix... its a shame Wacom doesn't release drivers themselves same with other hardware manufacturers such as Nvidia, etc... darn my laptop isnt powerful enough to handle compiling something that large... it crashes if I compile simple java applications due to maxing out my little Pentium processor... Cant believe i just spent money on a tablet that isn't supported at this time...

Again thanks for the feedback... going to leave this open as is still not "solved"

Comment: Neither the module nor the driver are large - give it a go at the weekend. Regarding Wacom: I think they simply don't want to be legaly responsible to provide support for the 200 distros out there - as far as I know at least some of the linux-wacom developers and especially the project founder are/were wacom employees. The reason for the 'delay' ATM is that they, as a policy, release new versions only when the necessary kernel changes are accepted upstream by the kernel devs. But the patches provided by jason are a 'quick hack' as he writes that make further changes to the kernel unnecessary.

Comment: Do you mean that at a later time compatibility will come automatically with the regular Ubuntu updates? And what is the expected time when this will happen (weeks, months, ...)?

Comment: That should indeed be the case -- possibly not via regular updates , but involving a ppa -- in a timeframe comprised of weeks AFAIK

Comment: A "personal package archive" - an additional source of packages you can tell your system to use -- I have added a dozen of them to get new versions of blender, a low-latency kernel, emacs 24, etc. for 12.04 -- read more about that in this article: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-ppa-technology-explained/

Comment: Sorry, I have just deleted my comment to which your last comment refers (saw this too late). My intention was to enhance my comment/question as follows: When Wacom will have released the new drivers, can I proceed as described in the first section of  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom/LatestDriver to get them? If yes, how do I have to adapt the 4th step in the description for CTH480?

Comment: I can't speak for the package archive owner -- if he/she updates the wacom-plus ppa accordingly then yes you can follow the steps mentioned there -- but there is no 4th step I can see regarding PPA; do you mean the uninstalling/reverting to ubuntu packages? That should work.

Comment: With 4th step I mean sudo apt-get install wacom-dkms ... it seems to refer specifically to the bamboo fun tablet and not to the CTH480. Anyway I followed the first 3 steps and for sudo apt-get update I got the message W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/doctormo/wacom-plus/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found ...

Comment: Same Problem for me... the PPA doesn't work for me when i run sudo apt-get update or sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: As a side note --- the [wacom project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/) released the 0.20.0 driver. In had just compiled it (no `xf86-input-wacom`) and it works on my 13.10. Is there something I am missing not compiling the x86 driver?

Comment: @Rmano Maybe, maybe not -- best to check the changelogs if you're unsure.

Comment: @Rmano: Can you briefly explain what I have to do with the driver? Sorry, I am new to Linux and have absolutely no clue how to proceed.

Comment: @lpdbw : I added an answer. Hope it helps.