# Wacom tablet intuos CTH480S don't work

Tags: tablet, wacom

I am running on ubuntu 12.04 (64bit).

I bought a wacom intuos tablet CTH-480S.

It seems recognized when prompted lsusb , 'ID 056a: 0302 Wacom Co., Ltd.'  appears.

But it does not work.

Manager settings for wacom tablet is installed, but does not detect tablet.

Thank you for your help, I do not know where to start.

Sébastien

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/a/390795/16395

Answer (score 1):

The following approach works for me on Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10:

- Download [input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2/download) from SourceForge
- Untar it and run `./configure`. It is necessary to have `gcc` installed to compile (`sudo apt-get install gcc`)
- Copy `3.7/wacom.ko` to `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/`
- Add `wacom` to `/etc/modules` because tablet is not recognized automatically and the module is not loaded without this.

The above worked fine for kernels 3.8.0.34 on Ubuntu 13.04 and mainline 3.12.6 on Ubuntu 13.10. I've installed 3.12.6 to check if its wacom driver contains recent changes but it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux Wacom folks are working on getting the new Intuos tablets to work right out of the box (the cth and ctl models).

If you feel confident with patching, you can get your tablet to work early - [read more on the Linux Wacom Mailing List](http://linuxwacom-discuss.996327.n3.nabble.com/Status-of-support-for-CTH-480-Intuos-Pen-amp-Touch-small-td7281.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm not confortable with patching, but it's opportunity to try.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this comment on this site. It seems that it is resolution for my tablet, but I do not know what to make with files input-wacom-0.20.0 mention in this announcement?
Somebody could help me?
Thank you.

[http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=linuxwacom-announce&max_rows=25&style=nested&viewmonth=201312][1]

---

> Its here! After an unexpectedly long wait for the patches to get 
>   accepted upstream, input-wacom now offers backported support for the 
>   three new "Intuos" tablets recently released by Wacom. If your new 
>   tablet has been sitting idle for the past few weeks, now's your chance
>   to start using it :) Grab a tarball and give it a whirl!
>
> Jason Gerecke (1):
>         input-wacom 0.20.0
>
> Ping Cheng (5):
>         Backport Bamboo One to 2.6.30
>         Not all multi-interface devices support touch
>         Scale up touch width and height values for Intuos Pro
>         Make sure touch_max is set for touch devices
>         Add support for three new Intuos devices
>
> git tag: input-wacom-0.20.0
>
> http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2/download
>   MD5:  86ec5c2a0a743889af6fa2e72b838f76  input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2
>   SHA1: d2a54d73dbd45152a7f622ec01e1f124e85792a8 
>   input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2

Comment: I find the solution here:  http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Input-wacom . But i'm stopped at the end of this tuto. After the command "depmod -a" , i'have this message: FATAL: Could not open /lib/modules/3.2.0-57-generic/modules.dep.temp for writing: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

I am using 3.11.0-15-generic

1. I got this working using [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Input-wacom) already posted link.
2. When it sends you off to download the latest release I only got this working with
   input-wacom-0.20.0 NOT xf86-input-wacom-0.22.1.
3. For the section 'Build / Install' I replaced 'kernel version' with '3.7' as the release did not have a version for my build (mentioned above).
4. For to the section called 'Module Loading' I chose to run the commands instead of restarting. The 2nd and the 3rd commands throw up errors, but ignore them and continue.
5. Open up 'Wacom Tablet' in 'System Settings' and you will see that your device has been recognized.