# Installing new wacom driver for CTH-680 or CTH-480

Tags: drivers, wacom

**Info: This is not needed in Ubuntu 14.04 anymore. The Tablets CTH-480 and CTH-680 work out of tho box now**

I bought a wacom graphic tablet and missed to look if it is supportet by ubuntu.
The Tablet is a cth-680 called "Intuos Pen & Touch".

I found, this answer on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368242/wacom-cth-480-not-detected-in-ubuntu-13-10) for a CTH-480. And the patch there seems to also include the CTH-680

My ubuntu version is 13.10

The tablet is found with `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 056a:0303 Wacom Co., Ltd
```

What i did so far:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libx11-dev libxi-dev x11proto-input-dev xserver-xorg-dev libxrandr-dev libncurses5-dev autoconf libtool libudev-dev


 mkdir ~/wacom
 cd ~/wacom
 git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom
 git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/linuxwacom/input-wacom
```

Then I downloaded and applied the patches:

http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/mailman/message/31592023/ as attachments to this post http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/mailman/message/31599376/

0001-Input-wacom-Not-all-multi-interface-devices-support-.patch

0002-Input-wacom-add-support-for-three-new-Intuos-devices.patch

```
cd input-wacom
patch -p1 < ~/Downloads/0001-Input-wacom-Not-all-multi-interface-devices-support-.patch
patch -p1 < ~/Downloads/0002-Input-wacom-add-support-for-three-new-Intuos-devices.patch
```

Then i compiled the driver:

```
./autogen.sh
./make
```

And did a backup and copy the new diver like so:

```
sudo cp /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko.BAK
sudo cp 3.7/wacom.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko
sudo depmod -a
```

**Step 2 (xserver driver)**

I didn't need to patch the xserver driver. Because it works on ubunt 13.10
So i compiled it:

```
cd ../xf86-input-wacom
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib
make
```

...and copied it over:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/wacom_drv.so /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/wacom_drv.so.BAK
sudo cp src/.libs/wacom_drv.so /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/wacom_drv.so
```

I rebooted the system, but still the tablet is not recognized.

Did i miss something?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution, it helped a lot! I noticed that if you download the tarballs from Sourceforge project, you don't need to the `autogen.sh` command, but need to run `./configure` in Step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to use the drivers from

[Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/)

directly and not the git repository.
Anything else is the same.

Comment: Which versions of the files did you download from Sourceforge?

Comment: It was 0.19.1 but keep in Mind: every time when there is a kernel update, yo need to install the drivers again. But then you can start at ./autogen.sh and ./make. You can skip the Step 2 for xserver driver.