# Intuous Wacom pen & touch cth-480

Tags: wacom

OK I have looked up a plethora of these questions on how to install them, and honestly I can't get it to work for the life of me.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, nor am I super experienced with linux.

When I read some of these instructions and they are even the slightest vauge, such as with not explaining from start to finish how to "cd" something, I tend to get rather lost.

So my question is, can someone just lay out for me in the most simple way on how to install my intuos wacom pen and touch cth-480 / cth-480/s?
And I mean every single step, I have tried and tried and simply cannot get it done. I was hoping to ditch my shite of a track pad that comes with this throwaway laptop but no such luck.

Comment: oops, that 7 is supposed to be the "&" symbol
Also I am running the latest version of ubuntu, 13.10 something. The 64bit version at that.

Comment: I wrote this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/390795/16395 --- I do not think I can put it more step by step, but have you tried it? I have the same object and it works ok. If you have trouble, copy in the question exactly what you did and what error you had.

Comment: well the cd part never works, so really I can extract that tar no problem, but that cd stuff doesn't work. I've tried typing it in a myriad of ways to get it to work, in case of interpretation error. I did adjust the names of thing to accommodate for file version but no such luck still.

Comment: So do the following: type the command and copy and paste the result in the question, I will have a look. I can even copy and paste the commands in that post and they work for me.

Comment: Look, I reinstalled it on my machine for you. In the following link you can find a live session of what I did --- the command I typed are the one preceded by `[...] %` ([...] means "whatever in brackets", this will change for you depending on your shell). The link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7192597/ . Note that the `ls` commands are not necessary, the means "list the content of the directory". Hope this help --- I cannot do more without knowing what exactly is your problem.

Comment: PC:~$ tar xjvf xf86-input-wacom-0.22.1.tar.bz2
tar (child): xf86-input-wacom-0.22.1.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
PC:~$

Comment: You have downloaded the wrong file. That one is the graphic (xf86 stands for xfree86) server driver, which you do not need. You need the file which is called exactly as in my post, which is the kernel driver! See? If you post the exact problem, we can help! :-)

Comment: ah... shite... ok I'll try that again. How do I cd though? I don't think I understand that completely. would it be $ cd ~/Documents/wacom-drivers (assuming that is where and how everything it spelled.)

Comment: Just type the cd command. The tar command will create the subdirectory when extracting the file. It is irrelevant from which directory you start. Open the terminal in the directory where you downloaded the file, for example with `cd ~/Downloads`. You should see your file when you execute the command `ls`, otherwise means it is not there...

Comment: ahh ok i'll try that

here are the results:

PC:~$ tar xjvf input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2
tar (child): input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: You are not in the directory where you downloaded the file! What does `ls` say? You really should read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandlineHowto ...

Comment: If I could understand that page I wouldn't be in this situation. I said I didn't understand how this all works, and that a step by step in retard terminology would be necessary.

Comment: So try `cd Downloads` - normally is where things go. After that, see if the file is there with `ls`. If you see it listed, start again from the tar. You're almost there. But you really should spend a bit of time with a Unix tutorial if you want really enjoy Linux. This http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-getting-started.htm is very good.

Comment: I know, but with this hellish mouse I only want to beat this thing with a sledge hammer. Now I finally got past where you were talking about. I was able to make some sense of what you put into that pastebin and copied it where I could. now I am at that spot where you need to type that cp command. but I get this:   PC:~/Documents/input-wacom-0.20.0$ sudo cp ./3.7/wacom.ko /lib/modules/'uname -r'/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/lib/modules/uname -r/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko’: No such file or directory

is that because I'm still in the documents?

Comment: The ticks surrounding the `uname -r` part of that line are back ticks, not normal ones. Why don't you simply cut and paste that line?

Comment: because I forget hotkeys don't work but right clicking still does while in terminal...

Comment: To paste in terminal is shift-ctrl-v

Comment: ooohhh you have to add shift? Sorry grew up on Windows of all things. And now it's working I just had to reboot. Thank you for putting up with me, for the new drivers I just repeat the things I figured out right?

Comment: Do not delete the directory. When and if the kernel is updated, go to the same dir, and do a `make clean` and repeat the steps starting from the ./configure command. I will mark this question as a duplicate now. Happy to have helped.

Comment: By the way, ctrl-v does not work in the windows CMD either... It is because it has to be passed to the shell. At least Linux has the shift Ctrl v trick.... Please upvote the linked answer when you have the rep to do it.

Comment: I didn't know that either, I've never had to use the cmd line for more than figureing out some networking things and the dxdiag stuff

Comment: saddly as it ends up, compared to the windows version of this install. Using it as a track pack is damn near useless. It's far to sensitive, and you can't adjust any of the useful gestures that this is capable of doing on the windows version. This is disappointing for me.

Comment: On second thought, I will leave the install at version 0.20.0 and just be happy it works. Still, besides the learning value of this the entire process was a waste.

Comment: You still have to recompile the driver as soon as your kernel is updated, otherwise it will stop working. You'll know that when after an update the tablet stops being detected. And yes, please ask wacom to better  support linux - they should be the one involved in releasing better drivers,not leave the community to struggle with reverse engineering them.