# Black Screen When Plugging in Intuos CTL 480 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wacom

I followed the instructions to install the wacom drivers from here: http://matthewwittering.com/blog/ubuntu-tips/how-to-install-a-wacom-intuos-ctl-480-tablet-on-ubuntu.html

But when I plug in the device, the screen goes black and I can't do anything at all. I just shut down the computer. When I restart it works, though.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have been victim of this [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)(1):

- On launchpad:
  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1310800
- Upstream: https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/bugs/238/

If it is it, a workaround is to issue

```
sudo modprobe wacom
```

**before** connecting the tablet. After doing that, you should have the driver loaded; check it with

```
lsmod | grep wacom
```

if you have an output like

```
[romano:~] 127 % lsmod | grep wacom
wacom                  62856  0
```

Then the driver has been loaded. If you are suffering this bug, now you can plug the tablet without problem. If your computer still crashes, you are facing another bug.

(1) It is a strange bug, because I was not able to reproduce it at will. For me it disappeared after upgrading the kernel and/or when I installed a locally compiled driver [as explained here](https://askubuntu.com/a/390795/16395).

Comment: When I do this modprobe says
WARNING: /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'modprobe'
WARNING: /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with 'modprobe'

What does this mean? Is this a problem?

Comment: Which distribution are you using? There is no `psmouse.conf` in my `/etc/modprobe.d/` folder. Anyway, it's a warning; shouldn't matter. I will add a bit more info on the answer.