# Information on input-wacom-0.30.0 for Intuos Art compilaton

Tags: usb, kernel, wacom

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and an Intuos Art from Wacom. I'm trying to make it work, and I've already found and read many things about wacom devices on Internet. I downloaded the

```
xf86-input-wacom-0.31.0.tar.bz2
input-wacom-0.30.0.tar.bz2
```

tars, but...

I installed the first one, and in practice nothing happens: `lsusb` "sees" the device, but I cannot use it. I then tried to install the second one, but the result was that when I plugged the device, the screen became black and the computer was blocked (then I uninstalled it).

My kernel is

```
alberto@Goccio:~$ uname -a
Linux Goccio 3.2.0-23-generic-pae #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 22:19:09 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Can `input-wacom-0.30.0.tar.bz2` be used with my kernel or does it need a more recent one ?

Answer (score 0):

The important one is the second one, which is the low-level kernel driver for the tablet --- I suppose that you followed the instructions in the [wacom on linux wiki](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom). Remember to reboot after the installation of the kernel driver (not strictly necessary every time, but safer).

I do not know if your tablet is  supported; you can [check here](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Device_IDs) and in the [mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/mailman/linuxwacom-announce/) (for example,  [the message about the 0.30.0 release](https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/mailman/message/34579565/)).

What you are seeing can be a [bug that is lurking around](https://askubuntu.com/a/506392/16395) --- if this is the problem, a workaround that works most of the time is executing `sudo modprobe wacom` *before* connecting the tablet.

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions in the wacom wiki. I have an Intuos Art, that is reported to be supported by the 0.30.0 release. I rebooted and then tryed to execute the `sudo modprobe wacom` command. Then i plugged the device but the same happens: black screen and no more. Unplugging it, I return back to the login screen. I don't know what else could be done.

Comment: Try to repeat it while in a Virtual Console (switch to it wit ctrl-alt-f1). You should have a Oops in the screen when plugging the tablet; copy it (I did it with a camera ;-)) and report it to the developers mailing list...

Comment: Monitor is black again: this is what dmesg gives(last lines)
`[ 1602.848037] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
[ 1603.018158] input: Wacom Intuos PT M 2 Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/input/input16
[ 1603.020164] input: Wacom Intuos PT M 2 Finger as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.1/input/input17
[ 1603.097314] show_signal_msg: 42 callbacks suppressed
[ 1603.097318] nepomukservices[4106]: segfault at 4 ip b7583028 sp ac5f98f0 error 4 in libQtCore.so.4.8.1[b7406000+2d4000]
[ 1633.496049] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 4`

Comment: No more (useful) ideas --- try to get in contact with developers, they are quite responsive. Maybe they can help you...

Comment: I did; I received a very kind answer. Probably the problem is in my computer: maybe a hardware one. Tomorrow I'll try with one back USB port (one I've never used in my life) and see.