# WACOM Connection to lappy

Tags: wacom

I tried to connect new Wacom CTH 301 K to my lappy HP-G6-2236tx using Ubuntu 14.04 but it shows the options of Wacom but didn't recognize the device. can any one help me in fixing this thing please.

Comment: Itś a different tablet, but you can check if there is a new driver. Look at http://askubuntu.com/a/390795/16395 --- newest driver is 0.23.0, maybe you are lucky.