# Wacom tablet (CTH-480) supported on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, wacom

I am currently using a Wacom tablet (CTH-480) on Ubuntu 13.10. This is possible because of the solution suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/a/390795

I would now like to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04. But before I want to be sure that my tablet will still be supported. Can anyone tell me whether my tablet will still work?

Comment: I found some info here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1310800 But it is not quite clear to me whether or not the Wacom tablet is working fine now on 14.04 or not...

Comment: It is answered in the thread you link to.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right, I am sorry, I didn't notice that the answer in that thread had been updated (how could I?). I'd suggest to delete my thread but maybe it helps people looking for advice on 14.04 to find the other thread (unlike that one mine is tagged 14.04 and has fitting title) ... up to moderators to decide.

Comment: For those still curious, it is still not yet working (causes kernel panic on hot plugging by default in Xubuntu 14.04).