# wacom tablet compatibility

Tags: tablet, compatibility, wacom, graphics-tablet

I am keen on knowing if the following tablets work out of the box with Ubuntu 12.04.

- Bamboo Pad CTH-301/K0-AX
- Intuos Manga CTH-480/S1-C

Strangely none of the specs mention anything about the Ubuntu or for that matter any Linux OS.

I need to buy one and the above two are the only models in stock (and within budget). The vendors have no idea and the product cannot be tested so I thought this post will help get some answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an Intuos CTH-480 (not Manga --- no idea if they are different; mine has also the 
wireless adapter) and it works out of the box in 14.04, needs manually compilation of the driver in older distro: https://askubuntu.com/a/390795/16395.

Notice however that the level of "works" depend on your definition --- the support for the tablet in Windows is greatly superior. For example, I am still struggling to define the tablet hardware keys.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Does your model support pressure-sensitive drawing?

Comment: Yes --- in GIMP and xournal it works.