# WACOM INTUOS CTH-680 doesn't work out of the box on Ubuntu 14.4

Tags: drivers, wacom

I bought a WACOM INTUOS CTH-680 but it doesn't work out of the box on the newest ubuntu version. I can draw in gimp but the buttons and the eraser don't work. There is also no recognition of the tablet in the System Settings. I googled and I found several threads which treats it. There are lots of how to's to solve it but all of them are for older ubuntu and/or kernel versions.
Can anybody help me?

I've got a Thinkpad X230 with 16gb RAM and i7 quad core.

```
$ uname -r
3.16.0-33-generic
demsg
[18103.085761] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[18103.183429] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=056a, idProduct=0303
[18103.183433] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[18103.183435] usb 1-1.2: Product: Intuos PTM
[18103.183436] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Wacom Co.,Ltd.
[18103.184133] input: Wacom Intuos PT M Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0>Y
 /usb1/1-1>/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/input/input23
[18103.184912] input: Wacom Intuos PT M Finger as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0
 /usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/input/input24
```

EDIT: I tested it at my girlfriends laptop also with ubuntu 14.4 and it worked. It must be a problem with my system.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [new version of input-wacom available](https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/mailman/message/33604438/); at this time [the most recent one here is 0.27](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/). You can try to see if compiling and installing it as explained in https://askubuntu.com/a/390795/16395 helps.

Given the release notes, you can now omit the cumbersome "cp" to install the thing and you must use `make` after the `configure` stage; I quote (I did not test it, my 480 works ok out-of-the-box):

> This release also slightly changes the build process. Whereas before
>   it was possible to configure and build the driver with a single
>   command, you must now run `./configure` and `make` as seperate steps.
>   Along with this, it is now possible to run `make install` to have the
>   driver automatically installed to your kernel modules directory (no
>   more manual copying!)

So the compilation step should be:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

There is a list of supported device IDs here: http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Device_IDs (you can get your own with `lsusb` after plugging it in). If it's not supported, the next step is asking the devolopers [via the mailing lists](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Mailing_lists).

In principle, you should also update the [xf86 driver](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/xf86-input-wacom/) and the [libwacom library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/libwacom/); I never did that because just the kernel driver solved the problem for me.

Comment: Didn't help. I did the steps but the tablet isn't recognized by the system settings yet and the gestures, buttons and the eraser still don't work.

Comment: In addition I have to mention that the make && make install step threw some errors

Comment: >make[2]: *** [_emodinst_] Error 1
>make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-33-    generic'
>make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
>make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/moon/Driver/input-wacom-0.27.0/3.7'
>make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Comment: These errors means that probably you haven't installed anything. Please open another question about compiling the input-wacom drivers, and report the exact steps you did and the errors in it.

Comment: ...a quick shot... did you prepend `sudo` to make install? You will need it. So it's `make` and then `sudo make install`.

Comment: ahh okay. Compiling worked without errors. But the tablet still doesn't work

Comment: new version in available... http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/mailman/message/34579565/