# -half resolved- Bamboo Pad not working in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, 15.04, wacom, bamboo

I got a Bamboo Pad graphic tablet, which does not work.
I'm running standard Ubuntu 15.04 on a Lenovo Yoga 2 pro.

I tried updating grub and other tips given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530205/how-to-get-bamboo-pad-working-on-ubuntu-14-04) which seem to work in 14.10, but do not seem to work in 15.04 (someone else had the same [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613608/wacom-bamboo-cth-300-not-recognized-and-not-working-in-ubuntu-15-04)).

Here is the result of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 056a:0318 Wacom Co., Ltd
```

Comment: You can give a shot at a new driver --- http://askubuntu.com/a/601691/16395 (but I really do not know if it will work).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got halfway there. Thank you all for your responsiveness.

1. using the usbhid.quirks trick did not change anything. This trick used to work in 14.10. It does not appear to work in 15.04
2. updating kernel to 4 made my pad work. I used the following method to [upgrade](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/linux-kernel-4-0-rc1-released-install-in-ubuntu-linux-mint)

Now only the stylus input work. The finger input does not, neither the bottom button. Adding the `MatchIsTablet "on"` did not solve this.

edit: when I run `dmesg | grep -i wacom`

here is what I get

```
 [    1.457401] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Wacom Co.,Ltd.
    [    2.813078] input: Wacom HID Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:056A:0318.0006/input/input13
    [    2.813174] wacom 0003:056A:0318.0006: hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [Wacom Co.,Ltd. Bamboo Pad, USB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
    [    2.813304] input: Wacom HID Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:056A:0318.0007/input/input15
    [    2.813393] wacom 0003:056A:0318.0007: hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Wacom Co.,Ltd. Bamboo Pad, USB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
    [    2.813545] input: Wacom HID Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:056A:0318.0008/input/input17
    [    2.813602] wacom 0003:056A:0318.0008: hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Wacom Co.,Ltd. Bamboo Pad, USB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input2
```

So a mouse is detected, additionally to two pens. How do I configure it to work?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug ([you can access it here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xf86-input-wacom/+bug/1265714/)) that seems to describe your issue. Although it's a *little* bit old, the solution should still work.

From the [#38 reply](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xf86-input-wacom/+bug/1265714/comments/38):

> Got it perfectly running, now someone can help to get it fixed for all
>   by default. So the steps are:
>
> 1. Add `usbhid.quirks=0x056a:0x0319:0x40000000` to the grub boot cmdline(`/etc/default/grub`). Now the tablet is already working with
>      wacom driver but automatically assigned wacom driver doesn't support
>      touchpad and it's keyboard part
> 2. I have added to `50-wacom.conf` (`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`) the line
>
>    ```
>     MatchIsTablet "on"
>    ```
>
> in the first section after
>
> ```
>      MatchProduct "Wacom|WACOM|Hanwang|PTK-540WL|ISD-V4"
> ```
>
> This way `evdev` works for keyboard and pad parts of the device and
>   `wacom` only for tablet
>
> Everything works, including three-finger swipes(which are sent by
>   keyboard driver as <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd>,
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd> etc) and pressure
>   sensitivity of pen! There must be a better way to match Bamboo Pad
>   without breaking the generic wacom file but I have no experience of
>   doing that, still I will try later if no one else does it faster.
>
> For the wired edition replace `0x0319` with `0x0318` in the grub
>   cmdline