# Cintiq 27qhd stopped working, now only registers first touch

Tags: wacom

I've connected my Cintiq 27qhd touch to my previous linux, Mint 17 and it only registered the first touch, moved the pointer once and stopped working. Shortly after I've returned to Ubuntu (lubuntu 15.04) and the Cintiq worked out of the box for a few days. After several times I've used it - the same problem reappeard on lubuntu - only the first touch is registered, which causes the pointer jump to a new location and stay there (other input devices continue to work normally, only the cintiq remains unresponsive)

Currently I'm running kernel 3.19.0-18, I've tried updating it to 3.3.0 as suggested on another post about wacom cintiqs but the update didn't work for some reason. Before retrying the update route, I thought I'd try figuring out if I can make it work with the current kernel as it worked pretty well for a while. 
Also I've tried using the wacom pen, which gave the same result. So it's probably not the touch thing.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have that tablet, but the new release of the wacom drivers --- [see the mailing list announce](https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/mailman/linuxwacom-announce/?viewmonth=201505) --- are specifically commenting things about Cintiq devices. Maybe is worth trying to compile the latest driver.

You can use my [old answer for 0.20](https://askubuntu.com/a/390795/16395) as a base, although I think the compilation method has changed a bit; see also [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/601691/16395) and the comments for help.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Rmano, Thanks for the detailed walkthrough! I tried following your gudie, unfortunatly because I'm on Lxde the ./configure command was missing some elements such as the  x11 and location of xorg etc.. so I'll try to see if theres a way to overcome that. (Total noob here)  I've noticed now that running dmesg command returned "wacom: probe of 0003:056A:032B:000C failed with error -22" if that's of any importance..