# Ubuntu 15.04 Wacom Bamboo Not Working

Tags: 15.04, wacom, bamboo

I've been trying to get my Wacom bamboo (CTH-300) to work under Ubuntu 15.04 without any success, I've tried every step from this previous question [How to get Bamboo Pad working on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530205/how-to-get-bamboo-pad-working-on-ubuntu-14-04) as well as following all directions from the provided links but nothing seems to work. One of the comments mentioned it working for his 14.04 but has not worked after upgrading to 15.04. Does anyone have any solutions or workarounds for 15.04?

Comment: Look also at http://askubuntu.com/a/601691/16395 --- maybe you need to install a more recent driver. Although if it worked in 14.04 and stopped working, it's probably a bug.

Comment: @Rmano, one of the directions was to get the newest driver that was 30 for me and unfortunately that hasn't worked either, thanks anyways