# Wacom Intuos art CTH-490 does not work ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, wacom

My Wacom Intous art "Creative Pen & Touch" CTH-490, which I bought today, does not work with ubuntu 15.04. 
When I go to settings -> Wacom tablet, I see that there is no tablet detected, even if the tablet itself seems connected (the blue light is turned on)
I tried to Google the problem and download some drivers but nothing worked.

May you help me to solve the problem? I do not have any windows computer, and using that tablet is an important thing for me.. 
Thanks! :)

Comment: You can try to compile and install the latest wacom driver, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/601668/wacom-intuos-cth-680-doesnt-work-out-of-the-box-on-ubuntu-14-4 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/601668/wacom-intuos-cth-680-doesnt-work-out-of-the-box-on-ubuntu-14-4 --- maybe you're lucky. See the wacom on linux page and ask them for  more help: http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that in http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Device_IDs your device is still not supported. You can try to contact the developers and help them to support it: http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Mailing_lists

Comment: Apparently the device is a part of the new Intuos line which was released 3 days ago. That's the reason why I could not recognize the tablet at the store... XD 
I mailed the wacom drivers team, and I'll update here as soon as I get a reply.

Comment: Saw it. BTW, when the developers are asking for the logs, look at  `/var/log/syslog` - when you plug the tablet there will be some message there, which is of utmost importance for them.

Comment: It detects the device in system logs, but it says "Invalid type 'stylus' for this device., Invalid type 'eraser' for this device. " etc

Comment: Yep --- send the relevant excerpt of  the logs to the developers in the mailing list --- [as they asked](https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/mailman/message/34436721/) --- that's the first step for them to try to support your device.

Comment: I did, no one answered so I do not know if they saw it..

Comment: They answered; "We're working on patches and will be submitting something to the Linux
kernel mailinglist soon. Once they're accepted upstream, we can add them
to our "input-wacom" driver which you can install to get the tablet
working on your distro."

Comment: Are there news on this? On 15.10 I still get

[  166.037699] wacom 0003:056A:033B.0007: Unknown device_type for 'Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos PS'. Ignoring.

Comment: If you have this issue, you can try my new builds for 15.04 and 15.10 here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom/LatestDriver if you are able to test, that would be great too.