# Can't set buttons on pad with Wacom Intuos Draw (CTL-490)

Tags: wacom, graphics-tablet

I have an Intuos Draw tablet, which should have 4 configurable buttons on the pad, and 3 buttons on the stylus. Unfortunately when I run `xinput list`, only the stylus is detected:

[image: xinput]

And when I try to do `xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus" Button 4 ""`, I get the error: `Invalid offset into Wacom Button Actions property.`, which means there are only 3 changeable buttons, aka the buttons on the stylus

Is there anyway I can change the buttons on the pad as well?

[image: pad buttons]

I also can't use the 'Wacom Tablet' settings window in system settings to set the buttons, as Ubuntu doesn't detect the tablet

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/685581/ubuntu-14-04-2-does-not-recognize-my-wacom-intuos-tablet-draw-ctl-490b

Comment: @FrankSchrijver I've already done that to make the stylus move the mouse, but that doesn't help rebind the buttons on the pad

Comment: xsetwacom --list devices
 should show more than 1 device then

Comment: @FrankSchrijver I followed the answer again and it still only detects the stylus. Unless I need to uninstall something first, I don't think that answer will help with my problem

Comment: Which Ubuntu version  are you using (lsb_release -a)? What is your kernel version (uname -r)?

Comment: @AaronSkomra "Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS" and "3.16.0-71-generic"

Comment: when I do a fresh install of 14.04.4 it gives me kernel 4.2, installing input-wacom-30 (current version is 31) the pad shows up in xinput and works. I will test out your kernel later, but I wanted to give you an update

Comment: I tried kernel 3.16.35 (from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D) and the pad also worked with that kernel. Your kernel isn't available at that url. You may want to try upgrading.

Comment: @AaronSkomra I updated my kernel to 3.16.35 and installed input-wacom-31, but I still only get the stylus. I can also try to update my kernel to 4.2 if you think it would help

Comment: @AaronSkomra I upgraded my kernel to 4.2.8, and the pad now appears in xinput, so upgrading the kernel appears to be the solution :D

Comment: glad to hear your tablet is working for you now