# Can't install Wacom on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, tablet, wacom

I first tried to install the Wacom driver by following this: [Ubuntu 14.04. 2 does not recognize my Wacom Intuos tablet draw (ctl-490b)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685581/ubuntu-14-04-2-does-not-recognize-my-wacom-intuos-tablet-draw-ctl-490b)

When I ran `./configure`, I saw this

```
checking for doxygen... no
configure: WARNING: doxygen not found - documentation targets will be skipped
```

I wasn't sure if that was a problem or not. I decided to follow this: https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/support-requests/49/

so I typed

```
sudo apt-get install xutils-dev libtool xserver-xorg-dev libx11-dev libxi-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libudev-dev
```

I then ran `make` and got

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0'
Making all in conf
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0/conf'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0/conf'
...
Making all in tools
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0/tools'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0/tools'
Making all in test
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0/test'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0/test'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0'
```

This seemed ok, so I then tried `sudo make install`

```
...
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/bin'
/bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c xsetwacom isdv4-serial-debugger isdv4-serial-inputattach '/usr/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c xsetwacom /usr/bin/xsetwacom
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c isdv4-serial-debugger /usr/bin/isdv4-serial-debugger
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c isdv4-serial-inputattach /usr/bin/isdv4-serial-inputattach
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0/tools'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0/tools'
Making install in test
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0/test'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0/test'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0/test'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0/test'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0'
...
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Downloads/xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0'
```

I assumed this meant there were no errors. However, I don't see Wacom anywhere. I even typed

```
xsetwacom --list devices
sudo find . -name wacom\* | grep modules
```

but there was no output for either of those commands.

`lsmod | grep wacom` just gave

```
wacom                  81920  0
hid                   118784  3 wacom,hid_generic,usbhid
```

I then followed this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom/LatestDriver

However, after `sudo apt-get install wacom-dkms`

I got

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.2.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/wacom/0.30.0/build/make.log for more information.
```

I then checked `/var/lib/dkms/wacom/0.30.0/build/make.log` and its contents are

```
DKMS make.log for wacom-0.30.0 for kernel 4.2.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Building input-wacom drivers for 2.6 kernel.
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-68-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/wacom/0.30.0/build/3.7
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.13.0-68-generic/build: No such file or     directory.  Stop.
Makefile:24: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Ubuntu version?

Comment: it is ubuntu 15.10

Comment: 15.10 is End of Live, unsupported and the software repositories have been moved. Please install 16.04 or 16.10. Outdated versions are unsupported here.

Comment: is it possible to install it without losing all my files and data?

Answer (score 0):

please try following the instructions to install the kernel driver at the official support page:

http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom

Comment: I already tried those steps

Comment: Just to be clear, there is a difference between xf86-input-wacom (xf86-input-wacom-0.33.0.tar.bz2) and input-wacom. You should be updating your input-wacom driver (input-wacom-0.32.0.tar.bz2)