# Wacom Intuos Draw tablet not recognized by Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb, asus, wacom

I have an ASUS laptop with Ubuntu installed on it. I go to the system settings and my tablet is not there. I have tried the https://github.com/linuxwacom way and followed the offical Ubuntu website (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom/LatestDriver), but nothing works. My laptop model number is U56E.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685581/ubuntu-14-04-2-does-not-recognize-my-wacom-intuos-tablet-draw-ctl-490b). Please specify your model number.

Comment: I means Wacom's model, not laptop :)