# Wacom Intuos Art Medium Compatibilty

Tags: 14.04, graphics, compatibility, wacom, support

I've been searching around and can't find an answer.
If you buy a Intuos Art will it work out of the box on Ubuntu 14.04?
I use Gimp if you're wondering.

The reason I ask is because I really want to get an Intuos without having to use Windows and I don't have a Mac.

Comment: The linux wacom has a lis of supported devices at http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Which_devices_are_supported.3F . You may need to install the latest driver: http://askubuntu.com/questions/368242/wacom-graphics-tablet-cth-480-ctl-480-not-detected-in-ubuntu-13-10 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/601668/wacom-intuos-cth-680-doesnt-work-out-of-the-box-on-ubuntu-14-4

Answer (score 0):

I use the Intuos Art with Ubuntu 14.04, and it doesn't work like I want. You can use it like a mouse, but you can't configure all of the buttons and the curve of Pressure rating.