# Wacom Intuos Art Medium crashes Ubuntu when using pen

Tags: wacom

I followed [this excellent tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368242/wacom-graphics-tablet-cth-480-ctl-480-not-detected-in-ubuntu-13-10/390795#390795) on how to get Wacom graphics tablet working.
After the installation, the tablet seems to work well, until I started using the pen. That's when Ubuntu freezes.

The tutorial used to work before, but when I switched to Arch Linux, this happened. I went back to Ubuntu and it happened again.

I am using Wacom Intuos Art Medium (CTH690) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS